# Inconsistent Output Bug and Code-Quits-Kernel Bug with Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, evaluation, compile, crash

This is the strangest bug I've encountered. In my experience, variations in the code will unexpectedly crash the kernel, give inconsistent output, or produce expected results with no problems.

### 1) Code-Quits-Kernel Version

***Warning: this will crash your kernel.***

To reproduce this bug, follow the steps below.

1. Copy the following code as is into a notebook. (It is all one cell.)

```
ClearAll[compbbbeven]

compbbbeven = 
  Compile[{{filled, _Integer, 2}, {prohibited, _Integer, 
     2}, {col, _Integer}}, 
   Union[
    Join[prohibited, 
     Flatten[
      MapIndexed[
       Function[{r, c}, Join[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]][First[#2], #1] &, 
       filled[[All, 1]]], 1]]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];

filled = {{1, 0}, {5, 0}};
prohibited = {{4, 4}, {5, 2}, {3, 3}, {6, 3}};
col = {1, 2};

Array[compbbbeven[filled, prohibited, col] &, 50] // Column
```

2. Quite your kernel.
3. Start your kernel.
4. Run the code from step 1.

### 2) No problems Version

This is the same code as in version 1 above except the 50 is changed to a 1 in the call to `Array`. Notice there is no kernel crash and output is produced with no error.

```
ClearAll[compbbbeven]

compbbbeven = 
  Compile[{{filled, _Integer, 2}, {prohibited, _Integer, 
     2}, {col, _Integer}}, 
   Union[
    Union[prohibited, 
     Flatten[
      MapIndexed[
       Function[{r, c}, Join[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]][First[#2], #1] &, 
       filled[[All, 1]]], 1]]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];

filled = {{1, 0}, {5, 0}};
prohibited = {{4, 4}, {5, 2}, {3, 3}, {6, 3}};
col = {1, 2};

Array[compbbbeven[filled, prohibited, col] &, 1] // Column

(*output is {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}}}*)
```

### 3) Inconsistent Output Version

Running the following code produces inconsistent output.

```
n = 6;
row = 3;
filled = {{1, 0}, {5, 0}};
prohibited = {{4, 4}, {5, 2}, {3, 3}, {6, 3}};

ClearAll[compbbbeven]

compbbbeven = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {row, _Integer}, {filled, _Integer, 
     2}, {prohibited, _Integer, 2}, {col, _Integer}},
   
   {Join[filled, {{col, 0}}, 
       Array[{0, 0} &, Length[#] - 1 - Length[filled]]], #} &[
    IntegerPart@Union[Join[prohibited,
       
       {{Mod[row + n/2, n, 1], Mod[col + n/2, n, 1]}},
       
       DeleteCases[
        Flatten[
         MapIndexed[
          Function[{r, c}, Join[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]][First[#2], #1] &, 
          DeleteCases[filled[[All, 1]], 0]], 1], {0., 0.}]
       
       ]]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C",
    Parallelization -> True];

col = {1, 2};
Equal @@ Array[compbbbeven[n, row, filled, prohibited, col] &, 50]
Equal @@ Array[compbbbeven[n, row, filled, prohibited, col] &, 50]
Equal @@ Array[compbbbeven[n, row, filled, prohibited, col] &, 50]
Equal @@ Array[compbbbeven[n, row, filled, prohibited, col] &, 50]
Equal @@ Array[compbbbeven[n, row, filled, prohibited, col] &, 50]
```

The output I received from running the code in one trial was as follows, but it changes from trial to trial.

[image: trial]

---

The original code was bigger, but I was able to reproduce the problems with the above shorter code segments many times. If the bug can be reproduced, I can update my question with shorter code exhibiting the same behavior found by others.

What is going on here?

### Notes

- My Mathematica is version 12.3.1.0 and my OS is macOS Big Sur Version 11.6
- The code quits kernel behavior was reproduced with Mathematica 12.3.0.0 on Windows 10 and with Mathematica version 12.3.1 on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). (see comments)
- There is a report the version 1 code runs fine with Mathematica 12.0 on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). (see comments)

Comment: Please give an example of the inconsistent output.  When I run this I get a "beep" with a message that states "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation."  If you get an error message, that should be added to your question (as opposed to stating that the kernel crashed).

Comment: @JimB No, I don’t get an error message. What happens to me is what happened to you. The inconsistent output comes from minor variations to the code, not the code as listed. I’ll try to reproduce that. Could you share your OS and Mathematica version? Thank you.

Comment: Did you hear a "beep"  and then look at "Why the Beep?..." under the Help menu?  But that certainly isn't informative other than to define what "crash the kernel" means.  However, if I change `{col, _Integer}` to `{col, _Integer, 1}`, it seems to work just fine.  *Mathematica* 12.3.0.0, Windows 10.

Comment: Also, if just `col = {1, 2};` is changed to `col = {{1, 2}};`, then it also works fine.  I know nothing about the compiler but might that be the issue?

Comment: It shouldn't quit the kernel as is. The code is junk - it doesn't do anything useful, but it should run just fine. Change the 50 to 1 within the call to `Array`. You may see that it doesn't quit the kernel (like I just saw now). So running the same code many times will produce a different result (kernel crash vs. no crash).

Comment: I can conform this. The code quits the kernel if run in _Mathematica_ version 12.3.1 on macos 10.15.7 (Catalina). "Why the beep?..." gives the most uninformative message "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.".  Typically, this is due to a segfault. But the code runs fine in _Mathematica_ 12.0 (on same OS).

Comment: Please file a detailed bug report at Wolfram Support. It may be a good idea to collect some more user experiences here in order to narrow down the error.

Comment: please report this at support@wolfram.com

Comment: @JimB I have updated my post with a version that gives inconsistent output.